# Has the /eureka/v2/apps been removed from spring cloud discovery dashboard

Tags: spring-cloud

I remember that I used to be able to access the older http://localhost:8761/eureka/v2/apps and could see the raw JSON for the apps form the discovery server (spring cloud).

I just tried it recently and no longer see it. Has it been moved? And if so, where?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I should have read further.  It was changed to http:/localhost:8761/eureka/apps.

Still works but change in URL